How to Include Custom `\newtcbtheorem` Environments in the Table of Contents?
I've created several new environments in LaTeX using the \newtcbtheorem command from the tcolorbox package. However, I would like these custom theorem environments to appear in the Table of Contents. Specifically, I want the ToC to display the theorems nested under their respective sections and subsections, like this:
1. Section Title
   1.1 Subsection Title
       1.1.1 Theorem 1
       1.1.2 Theorem 2
   1.2 Subsection Title
       1.2.1 Theorem 3

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Edit:
Here's how i define the environment, I don't think there's much to see (other environments just have different colors).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% Definition of the custom theorem environment
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{theorem}{Theorem}%
{%
  colback=blue!5,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries
  % I'm not sure how to include the theorems in the ToC here
}%
{thm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 1}{thm1}
This is Theorem 1.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 2}{thm2}
This is Theorem 2.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 3}{thm3}
This is Theorem 3.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Please show some code which explains how you define these environments and which commands and packages you want to use to create a ToC. Otherwise there is no way to help you in a reasonable way.

You could use the add to list option:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% Definition of the custom theorem environment
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{theorem}{Theorem}%
{%
  colback=blue!5,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  add to list={toc}{subsubsection}
}%
{thm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 1}{thm1}
This is Theorem 1.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 2}{thm2}
This is Theorem 2.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

\begin{theorem}{Title of Theorem 3}{thm3}
This is Theorem 3.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


